# A gap between list-items

Tags: html, css, list

I made a list containing several players but there are gaps between the list-items where there shouldn't be gaps. Here's the link: http://www.ostameerbeke.be/spelerskernB.html .

HTML:

```
        <ul id="beloften">           
            <li><a href="B1.jpg" rel="shadowbox[spelers]"><img src="B11.jpg" width="180px" alt="speler"/></a><p><strong>BUGDAYCI</strong> </p><p>Taner</p></li>
            <li><img src="spelerklein.jpg" width="180px" alt="speler"/><p><strong>CIRPI</strong> </p><p>Umit</p></li>
            <li><a href="B3.jpg" rel="shadowbox[spelers]"><img src="B31.jpg" width="180px" alt="speler"/></a><p><strong>DE BEULE</strong> </p><p>Bram</p></li>
            <li><a href="B4.jpg" rel="shadowbox[spelers]"><img src="B41.jpg" width="180px" alt="speler"/></a><p><strong>DE CONINCK</strong> </p><p>Toon</p></li>
            <li><a href="B5.jpg" rel="shadowbox[spelers]"><img src="B51.jpg" width="180px" alt="speler"/></a><p><strong>DE COOMAN</strong> </p><p>Rik</p></li>
            <li><img src="spelerklein.jpg" width="180px" alt="speler"/><p><strong>DE COOMAN</strong> </p><p>Wim</p></li>
            <li><img src="spelerklein.jpg" width="180px" alt="speler"/><p><strong>DE KEGEL</strong> </p><p>Gregory</p></li>
            <li><a href="B8.jpg" rel="shadowbox[spelers]"><img src="B81.jpg" width="180px" alt="speler"/></a><p><strong>DE NUTTE</strong> </p><p>Bram</p></li>
            <li><img src="spelerklein.jpg" width="180px" alt="speler"/><p><strong>DE REUSE</strong> </p><p>Laurens</p></li>
            <li><a href="B10.jpg" rel="shadowbox[spelers]"><img src="B101.jpg" width="180px" alt="speler"/></a><p><strong>DE SMET</strong> </p><p>Sigi</p></li>
            <li><a href="B11.jpg" rel="shadowbox[spelers]"><img src="B111.jpg" width="180px" alt="speler"/></a><p><strong>HAJIOUI</strong> </p><p>Yassin</p></li>
            <li><a href="B12.jpg" rel="shadowbox[spelers]"><img src="B121.jpg" width="180px" alt="speler"/></a><p><strong>LETTENS</strong> </p><p>Daan</p></li>
            <li><img src="spelerklein.jpg" width="180px" alt="speler"/><p><strong>LEYSSENS</strong> </p><p>Bedner</p></li>
            <li><a href="B15.jpg" rel="shadowbox[spelers]"><img src="B151.jpg" width="180px" alt="speler"/></a><p><strong>MOYSON</strong> </p><p>Pieter</p></li>
            <li><a href="B16.jpg" rel="shadowbox[spelers]"><img src="B161.jpg" width="180px" alt="speler"/></a><p><strong>NOTAERTS</strong> </p><p>Kevin</p></li>
            <li><a href="B17.jpg" rel="shadowbox[spelers]"><img src="B171.jpg" width="180px" alt="speler"/></a><p><strong>PAPPAERT</strong> </p><p>Pieter</p></li>
            <li><img src="spelerklein.jpg" width="180px" alt="speler"/><p><strong>ROBLEDO GONZALEZ</strong> </p><p>Adrian</p></li>
       </ul>
```

And Css:

```
    #beloften {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 0px;
}

#beloften li {
  margin: 0px auto;
  float: left;
  width: 170px;
  padding: 12px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Here is the working Jsfiddle of this code: [Working example](https://jsfiddle.net/hfj5a8tu/1/)

Comment: I'm getting no problem likes your page on JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/AgentStephens/ae24gL47/ so must be something in one of the parent elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having looked at your page i can see what your problem is.

You player images are `180x180` but your holder image is `180x182` the extra height on the holder images is causing it to display wrong.

Try:

1. Recreating the holder images as `180x180`
2. Adding on a `max-height: 180px;` to your img element

Answer (score 0):

Remove the padding

```
#beloften li {
  margin: 0px auto;
  float: left;
  width: 170px;
  padding: 12px; /* here */
  text-align: center;
}
```

Alternatively, have the padding be included in the width calculations by using `box-sizing`.

```
#beloften li {
    margin: 0px auto;
    float: left;
    width: 170px;
    padding: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    box-sizing: border-box; /* add this */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do text-align: center on the parent:

```
 #beloften {
    text-align: center; /* add this */
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

then remove the float from the list items and display them inline-block:

```
#beloften li {
    display: inline-block; /*add this */
    margin: 0px auto;
    /* float: left; */  /* remove this */
    width: 170px;
    padding: 12px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Which results in what I think you're after:

http://imgur.com/ESovzet

Answer (score 0):

Remove the float from the list items and display them inline-block:

```
#beloften li {
display: inline-block;
margin: 0px auto;
width: 170px;
padding: 12px;
text-align: center;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Remove the float from the list items and display them inline-block:

[image]

Css Code:

```
#beloften li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px auto;
    /* float: left; */ Remove
    width: 170px;
    padding: 12px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/hfj5a8tu/)

```css
#beloften li p {
    line-height: 0px;
}
```

use this with your css it will work

Comment: @vanberla pls check out the answer